# Join / Concatenate / Glue mp4 files to one file using mencoder

Tags: mp4, mencoder

I tried to concatenate some mp4 videos using `mencoder` like this:

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac pcm P10408*.mp4 -o new.mp4
```

When trying to play the new video I was asked to install some additional decoder **ITU H.264** Of course, I could install it but on the other hand `manpage` for `mencoder` claims that `-ovc copy` just copies the original without re-encoding.

So, apparently `-ovc copy` changed the format of the original mp4 (which I can replay without that H.264 decoder).

I also tried `-ovc raw -vf format=mp4` which generates a file I can replay without problems but is blown up to 10 GB (oroiginal files in sum are about 200 MB).

And I tried `-ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4` which generates a file I can replay without problems but lacks in video quality.

By the way, concatenating `.mov` files with `-ovc copy` produces a new file I can replay without problem.

**Question:**

Is there a way to use `-ovc copy` to produce a new file of the same format as the original files?

Comment: I use this as a workaround `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4` which I've found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg